# OpenLayers With StreetView Overlay

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

Im trying to add StreetView functionality to my OpenLayers web app, and would like to add the overlay showing StreetView availability to the map itself.  I have seen an example of it being done successfully [here](http://dev.geoext.org/sandbox/cmoullet/ux/StreetViewPanel/examples/StreetViewPanelExample.html?yaw=297.23&pitch=0&panoZoom=0&clickMode=true&videoTimeInterval=2500&showTool=true&showLinks=true&easting=738600&northing=5862000&zoom=14&panoEasting=740092.82894378&panoNorthing=5863392.1133842), but i cannot get the code to work in my own solution.  Specifically :

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Street", {sphericalMercator: true});

layer.mapObject.addOverlay(new GStreetviewOverlay());
```

results in the error:

```
layer.mapObject is null
```

Has anyone got any idea what i might be doing wrong, and if so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Openlayers with Streetview**

requires the GeoExt ux extension

all the code is available - so you can see what you are missing

(if you could post a live link to your current map - users could debug it for you.)

[image]

http://api.geo.admin.ch/main/wsgi/doc/build/api/streetview.html

Comment: +1 - this demo works. It is by the same author too, but more recent.

Comment: Would you know of any other way of using the StreetView Overlay Layer in OpenLayers without using GeoExt?

Comment: Only for Google Maps v2 (deprecated) http://fuzzytolerance.info/code/openlayers-with-a-google-street-view-widget/ API Key required.

Comment: GeoAdmin doesn't seem to offer Street View anymore, the closes relevant example I could find was: http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/examples/google-streetview-panel.html (OpenLayers + GeoExt)

Answer (score 2):

To use Google layers and meet licensing requirements you have to access Google layers through the Google API. When you add a Google layer to an OpenLayers map OpenLayers loads the Google API.

The `layer.mapObject` (as opposed to `layer.map` which is the OL map object) should give you a reference to the Google Map. As this is `null` something has gone wrong loading the Google API. You can check in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) if it has loaded correctly.

The example you point to may be using the older Google 2 API rather than version 3. You no longer need an API key and can add in the Google API using:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Have a look at the [unit tests for the Google v3 API layers](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/tests/Layer/Google/v3.html) which may help you.

Remember the StreetView also needs Flash in the browser.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help.  I'm not at my desk right now so I'm not going to be able to test your suggestions, but here's what I know:  I'm definitely loading the Google Maps API v3.  I have implemented StreetView in Web Apps before, but this time I'm looking to get the overlay on the map as well.  Im wondering though if its a browser thing.  The website I gave a link for works fine in IE (8) but not in Firefox...  any ideas?

Comment: The demo doesn't work for me in FF6, IE8 or IE9. It seems to only show either a map or a street view..

Comment: Hmmm,  the website seems to work in my IE8 here.... going to consult the OpenLayers user list as well now!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why layer.mapObject is null is that the mapObject property is created after that the layer is added to the map. Try this:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Street", {sphericalMercator: true});
map.addLayer(layer);
layer.mapObject.addOverlay(new GStreetviewOverlay());
```